# Практика pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Подскажите, пожалуйста, источники, где можно порешать задачки, чтобы прокачать навыки работы с pandas.

Comment: https://github.com/ajcr/100-pandas-puzzles

Comment: kaggle.com, конечно ))

Comment: @EmbraceTradition, полезная ссылка! Может оформите как ответ, чтобы вопрос не висел неотвеченным?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

github.com/ajcr/100-pandas-puzzles

очень хорошая ссылка